# Access iPad launch images programmatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, cocoa-touch, launchimage

I'm using `LaunchImage.launchimage` in `Images.xcassets` to manage the launch images. But I'm trying to use the launch images inside the app also.

I've read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19410066/ios-7-xcode-5-access-device-launch-images-programatically#19531369) :

> The documentation indicates that the **imageNamed:** method on UIImage
>   should **auto-magically** select the correct version

So, I used this code

```
UIImageView *backImage = [UIImageView new];
backImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"LaunchImage"];
```

When working on iPhone 4,5,6,6+ it works perfectly fine and get the correct LaunchImage, but when working on **iPad retina** it returns `LaunchImage-700@2x.png` which is the LaunchImage of **iPhone 4s** `640 x 960 pixels`

#### So how can I access the correct LaunchImage of iPad programatically ??

The contents of `Contents.json` in `LaunchImage` folder

```
{
  "images" : [
    {
      "extent" : "full-screen",
      "idiom" : "iphone",
      "subtype" : "736h",
      "filename" : "LaunchImage-800-Portrait-736h@3x.png",
      "minimum-system-version" : "8.0",
      "orientation" : "portrait",
      "scale" : "3x"
    },
    {
      "extent" : "full-screen",
      "idiom" : "iphone",
      "subtype" : "667h",
      "filename" : "LaunchImage-800-667h@2x.png",
      "minimum-system-version" : "8.0",
      "orientation" : "portrait",
      "scale" : "2x"
    },
    {
      "orientation" : "portrait",
      "idiom" : "iphone",
      "extent" : "full-screen",
      "minimum-system-version" : "7.0",
      "filename" : "LaunchImage-700@2x.png",
      "scale" : "2x"
    },
    {
      "extent" : "full-screen",
      "idiom" : "iphone",
      "subtype" : "retina4",
      "filename" : "LaunchImage-700-568h@2x.png",
      "minimum-system-version" : "7.0",
      "orientation" : "portrait",
      "scale" : "2x"
    },
    {
      "orientation" : "portrait",
      "idiom" : "ipad",
      "extent" : "full-screen",
      "minimum-system-version" : "7.0",
      "filename" : "LaunchImage-700-Portrait~ipad.png",
      "scale" : "1x"
    },
    {
      "orientation" : "landscape",
      "idiom" : "ipad",
      "extent" : "full-screen",
      "minimum-system-version" : "7.0",
      "filename" : "LaunchImage-700-Landscape~ipad.png",
      "scale" : "1x"
    },
    {
      "orientation" : "portrait",
      "idiom" : "ipad",
      "extent" : "full-screen",
      "minimum-system-version" : "7.0",
      "filename" : "LaunchImage-700-Portrait@2x~ipad.png",
      "scale" : "2x"
    },
    {
      "orientation" : "landscape",
      "idiom" : "ipad",
      "extent" : "full-screen",
      "minimum-system-version" : "7.0",
      "filename" : "LaunchImage-700-Landscape@2x~ipad.png",
      "scale" : "2x"
    },
    {
      "orientation" : "portrait",
      "idiom" : "iphone",
      "extent" : "full-screen",
      "filename" : "LaunchImage-700.png",
      "scale" : "1x"
    },
    {
      "orientation" : "portrait",
      "idiom" : "iphone",
      "extent" : "full-screen",
      "filename" : "LaunchImage-700@2x.png",
      "scale" : "2x"
    },
    {
      "orientation" : "portrait",
      "idiom" : "iphone",
      "extent" : "full-screen",
      "filename" : "LaunchImage-700-568h@2x.png",
      "subtype" : "retina4",
      "scale" : "2x"
    },
    {
      "orientation" : "portrait",
      "idiom" : "ipad",
      "extent" : "full-screen",
      "filename" : "LaunchImage-700-Portrait~ipad.png",
      "scale" : "1x"
    },
    {
      "orientation" : "landscape",
      "idiom" : "ipad",
      "extent" : "full-screen",
      "filename" : "LaunchImage-700-Landscape~ipad.png",
      "scale" : "1x"
    },
    {
      "orientation" : "portrait",
      "idiom" : "ipad",
      "extent" : "full-screen",
      "filename" : "LaunchImage-700-Portrait@2x~ipad.png",
      "scale" : "2x"
    },
    {
      "orientation" : "landscape",
      "idiom" : "ipad",
      "extent" : "full-screen",
      "filename" : "LaunchImage-700-Landscape@2x~ipad.png",
      "scale" : "2x"
    }
  ],
  "info" : {
    "version" : 1,
    "author" : "xcode"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved this issue using a long method

```
BOOL deviceIsIpad = NO;
if ( UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad ) {
    deviceIsIpad = YES;
}

if (!deviceIsIpad) {
    backImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"LaunchImage"];
} else {
    UIInterfaceOrientation interfaceOrientation = self.interfaceOrientation;
    CGFloat screenScale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
    if (interfaceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait || interfaceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown){
        if (screenScale > 1) {
            backImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"LaunchImage-700-Portrait@2x~ipad.png"];
        } else {
            backImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"LaunchImage-700-Portrait~ipad.png"];
        }
    } else {
        if (screenScale > 1) {
            backImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"LaunchImage-700-Landscape@2x~ipad.png"];
        } else {
            backImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"LaunchImage-700-Landscape~ipad.png"];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that those extensions (-700-Landscape@2x~ipad for example) are not recognisable.

Add the following item to your Contents.json just for testing purpose:

```
{
      "orientation" : "landscape",
      "idiom" : "ipad",
      "extent" : "full-screen",
      "filename" : "LaunchImage.png",
      "scale" : "1x"
}
```

Now try the imageNamed: method.

Or try the imageNamed: with the image full name:

```
backImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"LaunchImage-700-Landscape~ipad.png"];
```

Comment: if this didn't your too. you need to get the Images.xcassets bundle. please confirm. I will add the code that gets Images.xcassets bundle.

Comment: Sorry.. event after renaming `LaunchImage-700-Portrait~ipad.png` to `LaunchImage.png` and editing the `Contents.json`, nothing changed and still returning iPhone 4s image

Comment: But when using full image name like this `[UIImage imageNamed:@"LaunchImage-700-Landscape~ipad.png"]` it works.. but that will need much more codes to work well

Comment: I know. Thats never worked for me too. I believe that apple never rly supported this 100% for all these extensions. Only some works. The simple ones as @2x only

Answer (score 0):

**LaunchImage.launchimage**

Are you really using `Images.xcassets` to manage the launch images?
Aren't you using `LaunchImage.launchimage` instead?

If so, there comes the confusion. You cannot load using `[UIImage imageNamed:@"LaunchImage"];` from `LaunchImage.launchimage`.

**Canonical names**

- `LaunchImage.png`
- `LaunchImage@2x.png`
- `LaunchImage-700@2x.png`
- `LaunchImage-568h@2x.png`
- `LaunchImage-700-568h@2x.png`
- `LaunchImage-700-Landscape@2x~ipad.png`

`LaunchImage-700-`**Portrait**`@2x~ipad.png` is **not** in that list.

Comment: Yes, I'm using `LaunchImage.launchimage` which is inside `Images.xcassets`

Comment: Even after renaming `LaunchImage-700-Portrait~ipad.png` to `LaunchImage-700~ipad.png` and editing the Contents.json, nothing changed and still returning iPhone 4s launch image