# How to assign LaunchImage to UIImage

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

I am trying to assign the right LaunchImage for the Device/Dimensions to a UIImage.

This works only for a specific device in this case for iPhone6 portrait.

```
UIImage(named: "LaunchImage-800-667h@2x.png")
```

> Is there away where the right launchImage can be assigned to UIImage?
>
> When launching the app the right launchImage is used but **NOT** when
>   assigning launchImage to UIImage.

I also tried this, and it return a launchImage but not the right one for the device.

```
UIImage(named: "LaunchImage")
```

Comment: [possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19410066/ios-7-xcode-5-access-device-launch-images-programatically)

Answer (score 2):

A launch image is what shows up on the screen *before* your app runs.

Thus, you cannot specify a launch image in code (e.g. `UIImage(named: "LaunchImage")`, because the launch image appears before you code ever has a chance to run - there would be no place to *put* such code.

The launch image is determined entirely by settings in your *Info.plist* (plus the asset catalog if you are using that).

Comment: i guess, he wants to reach the launch image of the app after the app starts. Probably he will use it inside the app somewhere.

Comment: @meth But he _shouldn't_ want that. A launch image is an image _of_ your app, not an image to be shown _in_ your app.

Comment: i also think like that but as i commented under the question, there exists a question demanding this and some others around needed it before.

Comment: The question is not about how to get LaunchImage to work. (in my case it is working fine). The question clearly says how to assign a LaunchImage to UIImage. So basically how to access the assets folder and retrieve the right image for the device.

Comment: And by the way I am able to access the assets folder for launchImage like so UIImage(named: "LaunchImage-800-667h@2x.png"), but this will only return the right image for iPhone 6 but not for other devices. My main point here is how to be able to get the right image for assets depending on what device is used.

Comment: @Nouras Why not just make a different actual image set, based on the device type, consisting of the same image?

Comment: I thought since launchImage picks the right image for the device when launching the app then their should be a way to also pick the right image when assigning image to UIImage. To use the same images from launchImage I can use this list http://stackoverflow.com/a/20045142/5900874 It seems the closest solution so far.